# pdflatex error: Font msbm10 at 600 not found

Tags: pdftex

When using amsfonts, and \mathbb, I get the error above with pdflatex, but not with latex/dvipdfmx. I would like to render LaTeX in Inkscape, and this is the toolchain being used there.

The (very simple) test file I am using is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[\mathbb{N} = \{1,2,3,\cdots\} \]
\end{document}
```

The amsfonts package is installed and used, and I have the fonts installed:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/afm/public/amsfonts/symbols/msbm10.afm
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/amsfonts/symbols/msbm10.mf
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/amsfonts/symbols/msbm10.tfm
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/symbols/msbm10.pfb
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/symbols/msbm10.pfm
```

But in missfont.log, I have:

```
mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 msbm10
```

When running pdflatex, I get the following warning and error:

```
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file pdftex.map): cannot open font map file
] (./test.aux) ) </usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/dpi60
0/cmmi10.pk> </usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/dpi600/cm
sy10.pk> </usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/dpi600/cmr10.
pk>
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 msbm10
kpsewhich: symbol lookup error: kpsewhich: undefined symbol: kpathsea_cnf_line_env_progname
kpsewhich: symbol lookup error: kpsewhich: undefined symbol: kpathsea_cnf_line_env_progname
mktexpk: Cannot find mktex.opt; check your installation.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file msbm10): Font msbm10 at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Can anyone offer an insight into why I am getting this problem with pdflatex?

Thanks!

Comment: pdflatex can not open the map file: `pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file pdftex.map): cannot open font map file`.

Comment: Where is pdftex.map? And if it is not there, how can I create it?

Comment: normally it is in texmf-var in fonts/map/pdftex. And it is created by `updmap-sys`

Comment: Yup, got it: locate pdftex.map
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, this was a bug in the textlive-lib library that was missing some symbols (including kpathsea_cnf_line_env_progname). Upgrading to the newest version of the library fixed it (this is on Fedora 32).

See more information in https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1905248